# error when using File with ImagePicker Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

The error is with this line: `File selectedImage`

I only have dart.io imported, not even dart.html so I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.

here is the longer piece of code

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:random_string/random_string.dart';
import 'package:tennis_event_app/services/crud.dart';

class CreateBlog extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CreateBlogState createState() => _CreateBlogState();
}

class _CreateBlogState extends State<CreateBlog> {
  late String pass, authorName, title, desc;

  File selectedImage;
  final picker = ImagePicker();

  bool _isLoading = false;

  CrudMethods crudMethods = new CrudMethods();

  Future getImage() async {
    final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    setState(() {
      if (pickedFile != null) {
        selectedImage = File(pickedFile.path);
      } else {
        print('No image selected.');
      }
    });
  }
```

(this is not the entire code but just a larger piece)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution I Used:

I ended up changing `File selectedImage;` to `File ? selectedImage;`

Answer (score 0):

What exact error are you getting?

**Suggestion**
Please do well to put `setState((){...});` in the if-statement like this:

```
if(pickedFile != null){
   setState((){
      selectedImage = File(pickedFile.path);
   });
}else{
   print('No image selected');
}
```

and **Hot Reload.**

***SEE COMPLETE SOLUTION THAT WORKED FOR ME***

```
class _ImageSelectorState extends State<ImageSelector> {
  var imageFile;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Container(
            width: 200.0,
            height: 200.0,
            color: Colors.grey.shade300,
            child: imageFile != null
                ? Image.file(imageFile)
                : Icon(
                    Icons.image,
                  ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 20.0),
          //Button
          Center(
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _pickImage,
              child: Text('Upload Image'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  _pickImage() async {
    try {
      final picker = await ImagePicker().getImage(
        source: ImageSource.gallery,
      );

      if (picker != null) {
        setState(() {
          imageFile = File(picker.path);
        });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

***Result***
[image: This is the result of my little test]

Comment: The error message is "non-nullable instance field 'selectedImage' must be initialized.

Comment: I also get two warnings. They both state "The operand cant be null, so the condition must be true", does this have anything to do with the problem?

Comment: Why not make ```selectedImage``` File variable a var? I will update my answer with the code I wrote to test this and it works.

Comment: this works, but I can't seem to actually upload selectedImage file to firebase storage, could this possibly have to do with the variable being a var and not a file, or is this just an unrelated problem?

Comment: I'm believing it an unrelated problem. Are you getting any errors? Please, let's see the log

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out, thanks for trying to help anyways man!